# Subdomain Linux Azure server for two Virtual Machine(VM)

Tags: azure

I have 2 Linux VM on an azure server: product VM and dev VM.
I have my own domain is product.com and I used it for product VM.
Now I want to point a subdomain like dev.product.com for dev VM.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to point a subdomain like dev.product.com for dev VM. Is it
>   possible?

It is possible, we can add `A record` to map dev.product.com to dev VM.

=========================

**Update:**

we can add A record like this:
[image]

More information about create A record, please refer to this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-at-Register-com-for-Office-365-55bd8c38-3316-48ae-a368-4959b2c1684e).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please explain it clearly? I've tried to search how to create new CNAME, how to add record but have no document for Linux virtual machine. Can you send me docs instead? Thanks!

Comment: @JokerVu you have your own domain, so you should login domian registrar web page, for example, you buy domain name from Register.com, you can follow those steps to add A record, please refer to this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-at-Register-com-for-Office-365-55bd8c38-3316-48ae-a368-4959b2c1684e  and the Hostname type with dev, in this way, we can add A record to this VM.

Comment: @JokerVu Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.